# Using authorizationMatrix() in declarative pipelines

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using the project based matrix authorization in my pipeline scripts.

For this I use the Pipeline Declarative Directive Generator to declare the code snippets for the pipeline.

I have some issues with this.

1. I can find no documentation on the the function authorizationMatrix() and which options it supports. Same for the permissions used.
2. Generating such a directive results in a very lengthy code segment of the form as this:

```
            authorizationMatrix([
    
                // group authenticated user
                'GROUP:hudson.model.Item.Build:authenticated',
                'GROUP:hudson.model.Item.Cancel:authenticated',
                'GROUP:hudson.model.Item.Read:authenticated',
    
                // group R&D
                'GROUP:hudson.model.Item.Read:R&D',
                'GROUP:hudson.model.Item.Build:R&D',
                'GROUP:hudson.model.Item.Cancel:R&D',
                'GROUP:hudson.model.Item.Configure:R&D',
    
                // project admin grafra1969
                'USER:com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Create:grafra1969',
                'USER:com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Delete:grafra1969',
                
           
     'USER:com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.ManageDomains:grafra1969',
                'USER:com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.Update:grafra1969',
                'USER:com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.View:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Build:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Cancel:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Configure:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Delete:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Discover:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Move:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Read:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Item.Workspace:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Run.Delete:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Run.Replay:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.model.Run.Update:grafra1969',
                'USER:hudson.scm.SCM.Tag:grafra1969',
```

Is there a good way to use helper function to generate these permissions. e.g.

```
   authorizationMatrix([
     permissionBuilder
       .withGroup( 'R&D')
       .withAdmin( 'grafra1969')
```

Are there some best practices, which could help here. e.g. inherit the permissions from a folder or something else?